# Connecting to my SQL database in azure from spring BOOT

Tags: mysql, azure, spring-boot

I am trying to connect my SQL database deployed in Azure from my spring BOOT application.Below is my application.properties file.when I run the application it is throwing some hibernate exceptions and also it is saying a maximum number of connections.Even If I close all connections and updated my password also but it's still the same error.Can anyone please help me how to do it in a correct way.
 please guide me
 Do I need to add any cloud dependencies?

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://**Datasource**/Databasename
spring.datasource.username=*****
spring.datasource.password=*****
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

**Exceptions are**

```
1. com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: User '*******' has exceeded the 'max_user_connections' resource (current value:4)
2.Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]

Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
```

Comment: "...throwing some exceptions". Like what? It's important to be more specific here.

Comment: Hi tadman u can see the exeption below

Comment: Edit the question to add additional information. Do not use the answer field for comments or explanations.

Comment: No worries, just trying to keep things organized. It helps when people are looking for questions to answer.

Comment: i think it has nothing to do with your configuration. looks like your database is not accepting any more connections. Check the db configuration and try, also you can check by creating a simple datasource and providing the information there and trying to get the connection using the data in a simple web app.